# Keyboard.IsKeyDown() in .NET returning incorrect value?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, keypress

I set the event for my `RichTextBox` in *WPF*:

```
_window._richTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += _richTextBox_PreviewKeyDown;
```

Then in `_richTextBox_PreviewKeyDown` I get information about currently pressed keys on keyboard:

```
bool isAltPressed = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt);
bool isCtrlPressed = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl);
bool isShiftPressed = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift);
```

Then I press only "RightAlt" key on keyboard.

When first time the *breakpoint* in `_richTextBox_PreviewKeyDown` is hit

- `isAltPressed = false`
- `isCtrlPressed = true`

(because `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)` returns `true`) and `isShiftPressed = false`.

Only after the second hit of the breakpoint

```
`isAltPressed = false`
```

Can someone explain to me such strange behavior?
Is it somehow possible to check the 'real' pressed keys on the keyboard? Finally when I press Right Alt on keyboard `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) = true` which is misleading.

Comment: Hmm, if I recall correctly the right ALT key (or AltGr on German layout) is a combination of Ctrl and Left-Alt. Maybe in your case only the first - meaning the Ctrl-Button - is registered in this case. 
I could be wrong though, but I think I had a similar case once...

Comment: When the breakpoint is hit again - the right Alt key press is registered. Is there any way to get the 'real' values if Left Ctrl, Right Ctrl, Left Alt and Right Alt keys are pressed at the current moment?

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure. I'm guessing you can access the e.Key Object in your function? I think there is additional information (modifiers and such) which you could use to detect the right Alt-key?